# Linq query for selecting record

Tags: c#, linq

We have use the following code snippet to select the particular `object` from `collection` based on the Name `property`.

```
        ObservableCollection<Test> collection = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        collection.Add(new Test() { Id =1, Name ="Nestor"});
        collection.Add(new Test() { Id = 2, Name = "Rohan" });
        collection.Add(new Test() { Id = 3, Name = "Guy" });
        collection.Add(new Test() { Id = 4, Name = "Mike" });

        string s = "Rohan";
        var temp = collection.FirstOrDefault(x =>
            {
                if (x.Name != null)
                {
                    return x.Name.ToString().Equals(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    return x.Name;
                }
            });
```

We got the following error in this code snippet.

Error:

> Error  1   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type   C:\Users\vadiveln\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication12\WindowsFormsApplication12\Program.cs  36  25  WindowsFormsApplication12
>   Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'   C:\Users\vadiveln\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication12\WindowsFormsApplication12\Program.cs  36  32  WindowsFormsApplication12

Can you please look into this and provide the suggestion to use the correct way of `Linq query`. Thanks in advance.

**Modified code below:**

```
        ObservableCollection<Test> collection = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        collection.Add(new Test() { Id = 1 });
        collection.Add(new Test() { Id = 2, Name = "Rohan" });
        collection.Add(new Test() { Id = 3, Name = "Guy" });
        collection.Add(new Test() { Id = 4, Name = "Mike" });

        string s = "Rohan";
        var temp = collection.FirstOrDefault(x =>
        {
            return x.Name.Equals(s);               

        });
```

We have use the null filed in the underlying collection. Then how to use the linq query

Comment: Your lambda returns a `string` or a `bool` depending on the branch it's taking.

Comment: Isn't x.Name already a string? Why the ToString()?

Comment: erm... to all you... wouldn't collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x == s); be comparing the objects Test with the string s? So surely it should be collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == s)

Comment: Don't use `.Equals(s)` method. Simply compare two strings with `==`

Answer (score 1):

It should be as easy as `var temp = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == s);`

Answer (score 1):

The return types are different.

```
if (x.Name != null)
{
    return x.Name.ToString().Equals(s); // returns bool
}
else
{
    return x.Name; // returns string (or null)
}
```

What you probably need is:

```
collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x == s);
```

Answer (score 0):

The lambda expression you pass into [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) needs to return a Boolean. Try this:

```
string s = "Rohan";
var temp = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.Name != null) &&
                                          (x.Name.Equals(s)));
```

Or more simply:

```
var temp = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == s);
```

`FirstOrDefault` can return null if no items are found matching your criteria, so it's a good idea to check for null values before using `temp`:

```
if (temp == null)
{
    // not found...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to get first item which has name equal to `Rohan`:

```
// Name is string, you don't need to call ToString() for comparison
var temp = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == s);
```

What's wrong with your current query? `FirstOrDefault` method requires predicate parameter, which returns boolean result. But currently you are trying to return string `x.Name` from predicate.

```
var temp = collection.FirstOrDefault(x =>
    {
        if (x.Name != null)
        {
            // this is OK, you are returning boolean                
            return x.Name.ToString().Equals(s);
        }
        else
        {
            // instead of return x.Name which is string
            return false;
        }
    });
```

---

Your modified code throws error, because some objects from collection can have `Name` property equal to `null`. When you are trying to call `null.Equals(s)` you get a `NullReferenceException`. To fix this simply compare two strings:

```
   var temp = collection.FirstOrDefault(x => 
              {
                  //return x.Name.Equals(s);
                  return x.Name == s; // will not throw if name is null
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're trying to achieve, but you're totally doing it wrong :)

```
var temp = collection.FirstOrDefault(x =>
    {
        if (x.Name != null)
        {
            // this part returns bool
            return x.Name.ToString().Equals(s);
        }
        else
        {
            // this one returns string
            return x.Name;
        }
    });
```

I think you're looking for really simple `FirstOrDefault(x => x == s);` here.

Answer (score 0):

FirstOrDefault takes in a delegate that returns TRUE or FALSE for every element in collection.

Inside your ELSE you need to compare `x.Name` to `s`:

```
return x.Name.Equals(s);
```

, not just

```
 return x.Name;
```